# OAuth authentication in Bigcommerce using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, oauth, oauth-2.0, bigcommerce

I am building an application for which I have to connect Webservices provided by Bigcommerce using OAuth authentication. I have search and found an example in Stack overflow . In that example it is saying that I have to supply few information in the authentication process.
The chunk of the code is like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("client_id={0}", clientID);
sb.AppendFormat("&client_secret={0}", clientSecret);
sb.AppendFormat("&code={0}", tempToken);
sb.AppendFormat("&scope={0}", scopes);
sb.AppendFormat("&grant_type=authorization_code");
sb.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", callbackURL);
sb.AppendFormat("&context={0}", storeContext);
```

I have the client id and client secret with me but I am not clear about temptoken and storeContext section.In the storecontext section it is saying that
I need to give a format with store hash . How can I get the store hash for my store. And what I have to pass in the temptoken section of the code.

Please guide me.

Thanks and Regards
Utpal Maity

Answer (score 0):

Both the code and the context are sent to your application's auth callback URL as query parameters once a user grants your application permission through single click install on the Bigcommerce app store.

```
GET /auth?code=qr6h3thvbvag2ffq&scope=store_v2_orders&context=stores/g5cd38 HTTP/1.1
```

The tempToken variable should be set to the code value and the storeContext variable should be set to the context value.

Remember to make sure that your auth callback URL uses SSL protocol and is public facing so that you can receive the callback from Bigcommerce.